# Magento2 : Remove decimal from quantity in product grid in magento admin

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I want to remove .000 after quantity in admin grid is there any way to remove decimal from quantity column.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the below steps for remove decimal from qty :

You need to add sequence in your **module.xml** file

```
<module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_CatalogInventory"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Create **product_listing.xml** file at

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="qty" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\QtyFile">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Quantity</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">75</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Add Renderer file **QtyFile.php** at

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/QtyFile.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

class QtyFile extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item[$fieldName])) {
                    $item[$fieldName] = (int)$item[$fieldName];
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Then, Upgrade your module and clean cache.

[Reference](https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-remove-decimals-from-quantity-in-product-grid/)